# SpringBoot getting started: Failed to start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created my first spring boot project and I have copied the example verbatim from [springs offical website](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

However, when I try to start using `mvn spring:run`, it fails with the following exception:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say if your project is web project or not. Also since I  don't see your `application.properties` or `application.yaml`. There could be so many reason and with limited amount of information on your question, I am trying to guess the answer.

If this doesn't work. update your question with more information.

If your project is not a web application project, try setting following on your `application.properties`

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

And if you have `application.yaml`, set thefollowing

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: none
```

Answer (score 0):

With limited information, its hard to say whats wrong in your application. I had a similar issue and I believe it was due to corrupted jar files downloaded. I resolved referring [this github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12398).

Answer (score 0):

There might be below reasons for  `ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean`

1. You might have missing web dependency in you pom

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. You have not annoted `@SpringBootApplication` to your main class:

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class Application {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
      }
   ```

   }